opensource PyMOL compiling-install issue
Hi I am playing a little bit with  schrodinger /
pymol-open-source 
Trying to figure out how : python setup.py install works I found documentation in
    pymol-open-source/INSTALL :
 SETUP OPTIONS

    python setup.py --help
    python setup.py --help-distutils
    python setup.py --help-distutils install

    Special install options:
      --pymol-path=       installation directory for PyMOL data ($PYMOL_PATH)
      --no-launcher       skip installation of the pymol launcher

While python setup.py --help works
python setup.py --help-distutils and python setup.py --help-distutils install dont.
I can build/install it passing:
python setup.py install --prefix=... --install-lib=... --install-scripts=...
like description in User:Tlinnet/Linux Install
bu why the help options don't work ?
I am new to Python setuptools etc , please bear with me
ADDENDUM
pip install works too
crossposted to stackoverflowopensource-pymol-compiling-install-issue

It looks like the documentation is wrong. At least, I don't see those options mentioned anywhere in setup.py and after git clone https://github.com/schrodinger/pymol-open-source, there are no hits for help-distutils anywhere except from the INSTALL file itself:
$ grep -R help-distutils pymol-open-source/
pymol-open-source/INSTALL:    python setup.py --help-distutils
pymol-open-source/INSTALL:    python setup.py --help-distutils install

The option used to be there, in the previous release. If you look at the setup.py from version 2.5.0 (https://github.com/schrodinger/pymol-open-source/blob/v2.5.0/setup.py), you can see the --help-distutils option was there:
    parser.add_argument('--help-distutils', action="store_true",
            help="show help for distutils options and exit")

So it is simply a bug: they have changed the code but forgot to update the documentation. I suggest you report it to the developers so they can fix it.

mmhhh wondering why 'setup.py --help-commands' works, its not in argparser option too but works

@pippo1980 presumably that's part of one of the libraries loaded by the tool. Perhaps setuptools, but this (delving deep into the code of some program) really is beyond the scope of the site. You can try asking the developers instead.

yep, was just trying to make my mind clear,  setup.py 2.5 is for "This script only applies if you are performing a Python Distutils-based installation of PyMOL"; while master : "This script only applies if you are performing a Python setuptools-based installation of PyMOL". I believe distutils was deprecated in 2021 https://peps.python.org/pep-0632/. Sorry for clogging the comments, it is  for self reference. Guess options, sys.argv[1:] = parser.parse_known_args(namespace=options) is what does the trick ... but not an expert in sys.argv
